# Estimate normal distribution variance from two observations

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

A simple question (not a homework question, although it seems to be):

Assume that $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, $\mu$ is known (say $\mu = 150$) and $\sigma$ is not known. If $x_1$, $x_2$ are 2 observations of $X$ what can be said about the distribution of the standard deviation $\sigma$?

Comment: When $\mu$ is known you can estimate $\sigma$ from even a single observation.  Note, however, that **$\sigma$ does not have a distribution.** Shall we presume you are asking about some *estimator* of $\sigma$?  In which case, *what is your estimator?*

Comment: Ok, no distribution is required. Could you please mention the appropriate method to estimate $\sigma$ (maybe a link)?

Comment: There are several.  Many would use the square root of (the usual least squares) unbiased estimate of $\sigma^2,$ but other (biased) estimates exist with smaller estimation variances.  The choice depends on your objectives and your loss function, as well as how certain you are that the true mean is $\mu$ and that the distribution is Normal.

Comment: Actually, this is a question of my colleague and he is pretty sure about normality of the distribution. I found [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation) providing the details. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a normal population where $\mu$ is known and $\sigma^2$ is not, an unbiased estimate of $\sigma^2$ based on a random sample $X_1, X_2, \dots X_n$ of size $n$ from the population is
$$ V = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \mu)^2.$$

Furthermore, $nV/\sigma^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n),$ so that
$$P(L \le nV/\sigma^2 \le U) = P(nV/U \le \sigma^2 \le nV/L) = 0.95,$$ for values $L$ and $U,$
which cut probability .025 from the lower and upper tails of $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n),$
respectively. Thus a 95% confidence interval for $\sigma^2$ is of the form
$(nV/U, nV/L).$ A 95% confidence interval for $\sigma$ can be found by taking square roots of the endpoints of the CI for $\sigma^2.$

*Example:* Take a sample of size $n=2$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=50, \sigma=3),$ assuming
$\mu = 50$ to be known, and using the sample to estimate $\sigma^2,$ and thence to estimate $\sigma.$ (Computations in R.)

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rnorm(2, 50, 3)
v = (1/2)*sum((x-50)^2);  v
[1] 6.902886              # estimate V of 9
```

With only $n=2$ observations, we cannot expect a precise estimate of $\sigma^2 = 3^2 =9.$
A 95% CI for $\sigma^2$ is $(1.871, 272.65).$

```
2*v/qchisq(c(.975,.025), 2)
[1]   1.871269 272.649441
```

Taking square roots of endpoints, we get a 95% CI for $\sigma.$

```
sqrt(2*v/qchisq(c(.975,.025), 2))
[1]  1.367943 16.512100    # CI contains the population SD = 3.
```

---

*Notes:* (1) All of the above is somewhat different from the situation where $\mu$ is
also unknown and estimated by $\bar X.$ This is the situation in your Wikipedia link.

(2) We have $E(V) = \sigma^2,$ so the estimator $V$ is unbiased for $\sigma^2,$ but
$E(\sqrt{V}) \ne \sigma,$ exactly.

One can follow a procedure similar to the
one in your link to find an unbiased estimator $c\sqrt{V}$ with $E(c\sqrt{V}) = \sigma.$

Because you are interested in $n = 2$ it may be of interest to use simulation to approximate $c = \sqrt{\pi/2}$ in that particular case. Below we obtain $c\approx 1.253.$ (Perhaps see [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution).)

```
set.seed(2020)
v = replicate(10^6, (1/2)*sum(rnorm(2))^2)
1/mean(sqrt(v))
[1] 1.252772     # unbiasing constant

set.seed(612)
v = replicate(10^6, (1/2)*sum(rnorm(2, 50, 3)-50)^2)
mean(1.253*sqrt(v))
[1] 2.997461     # aprx E(SD) = 3
```

> For an analytic derivation of $c$ you can use the integral $\int_0^\infty wf_W(w)\, dw,$ involving the density function of $W=\sqrt{V}.$ Except for the constant, the integrand is a gamma density. Factor out a constant so that the integrand ***is*** a gamma density (hence the integral is $1.)$ The constant you factored out is the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer.

Comment: Of course, the CIs would be shorter with more than $n=2$ observations. With $n=10,$ the avg length of the CI for $\sigma^2=9$ would be less than 24: `diff(10*9/qchisq(c(.975,.025),10))` returns 23.32428. And the length of a CI for $\sigma=3$ would be around 4.